# Nginx + node = get style.css, bundle.js Connection Refused

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, nginx-config, connection-refused

I'm having trouble uploading my static files to my server,
keeps giving "Connection refused" problems:

[image: console log]

I checked my firewall, but I didn't find anything that could cause a problem.

my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/pedroportifol.com.br settings

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name pedroportifol.com.br;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        deny all;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_buffers 4 32k;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        image/svg+xml;

    access_log off;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/pedroportifol.com.br-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/pedroportifol.com.br-error.log;

    #include /etc/nginx/common/protect.conf;
}
```

Could someone please help me?

I checked the firewalls and ports, but found nothing